# Set localStorage to a domain not loaded yet

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

Good Afternoon,

I want to set a localStorage to another domain. I used the postMessage function.
Here is the parent page :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
var childwin;
const childname = "popup";
function openChild() {
childwin = window.open('Page2.html', childname, 'height=300px, width=500px');

}
function sendMessage(){
    let msg={pName : "Bob", pAge: "35"};
    // In production, DO NOT use '*', use toe target domain
    childwin.postMessage(msg,'*')// childwin is the targetWindow
    childwin.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type='button' id='btnopen' value='Open child' onclick='openChild();' />
            <input type='button' id='btnSendMsg' value='Send Message' onclick='sendMessage();' />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the children :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
// Allow window to listen for a postMessage
    window.addEventListener("message", (event)=>{
// Normally you would check event.origin
        // To verify the targetOrigin matches
        // this window's domain
        let txt=document.querySelector('#txtMsg');
        localStorage.setItem("age", event.data.pAge);
        // event.data contains the message sent
        txt.value=`Name is ${event.data.pName} Age is  ${event.data.pAge}` ;

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Recipient of postMessage</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <input type='text' id='txtMsg' />
            </fieldset>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine but we need 2 buttons. One to open the page, the other to post the message.

If I want to make the two methods openChild();postMessage() in the same button, it does not work.

I think it is because the page2.html is not totally loaded when we call postMessage().

How can we do ?

Best regards.

Christophe.

Answer (score 0):

you can include your script when DOM loads

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

//do some functions

})
```